# Nice HTML Formatting in PHP for-loop Output

Tags: php, html, for-loop, formatting

I'm pretty sure I found no answer here or elsewhere or maybe because it's my fault not being able to ask the right question, but anyway, say I have a for-loop in my PHP that goes something like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
echo "<a href=\"\">$i</a> | ";
}
```

How do I make the last call for " | " to not appear in order to have a nicely output:

```
<a href="">0</a> | <a href="">1</a> | <a href="">2</a>
```

INSTEAD OF

```
<a href="">0</a> | <a href="">1</a> | <a href="">2</a> | <-- remove this! :(
```

You guys are fabulous! Thanks!!!

What if $i < $undefinedNumber ?

Answer (score 2):

Keep the flow, you only need that if it's not the first:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    echo $i ? " | " : '', "<a href=\"\">$i</a>";
}
```

And for the first `$i` is `0` which means it's `false`. Otherwise `$i` is a positive integer, which means `true`.

Sometimes finding an alternative way to describe the problem helps to formulate a simpler answer. Instead of:

```
<a href="">0</a> | <a href="">1</a> | <a href="">2</a> |  /* <-- remove this! :( */
```

It's that problem:

```
/* :( remove this! --> */ | <a href="">0</a> | <a href="">1</a> | <a href="">2</a>
```

---

The same form of solution works for CSS, too:

```
a:not(:first-child):before {content: ' | '}
```

sometimes that's easier to integrate than fiddling with PHP and HTML ([Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XAJ7zq)) - however that adds the `|` to the link-text or style (at least in chrome where I tested it, looks buggy).

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
   echo "<a href=\"\">$i</a>"
   if ($i != 2) {
      echo " | ";
   }
}
```

or

```
echo "<a href=\"\">0</a>";
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){
   echo " | <a href=\"\">$i</a>"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
    if ($i == 0) {
       echo "<a href=\"\">$i</a>;
    }
    else {
       echo " | <a href=\"\">$i</a>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you just need to remove the last bar from the output?  Why not skip it as you loop?  Something like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
{
    echo "<a href=\"\">$i</a>";

     if($i < 2)
         echo "|";
}
```

This would ensure that the bar only shows after the first two links, and not after the third.

Answer (score 1):

```
$output=array();
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    $output[]="<a href=\"\">$i</a>";
}
$ouput=implode(' | ', $ouput);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array();

for ($i=0; i<3; i++)
    $arr[] = "<a href=''>$i</a>";

echo implode(" | ",$arr);
```

---

More compact version:

```
echo implode(" | ", array_map(function($x){return "<a href=''>$x</a>";},range(1,3)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
    $arr[] = "<a href=\"\">$i</a>";
}
echo implode(' | ',$arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a commonly found situation in programming known as the Special Case pattern. There is no built in way of solving this other than using an if statement or the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Perl.2C_PHP)

```
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    echo "<a href=\"\">$i</a>" . ($i != 2) ? " | " : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it in the php, do it in the stylesheet.

First build your HTML

```
<ul class="navlinks">
     <?php foreach($links as $linkName => $linkUrl): ?>
     <li><a href="<?php echo $linkUrl; ?>"><?php echo $linkName; ?></a></li>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Apply the CSS.

```
.navlinks > li:after
{ 
    content:"<li>|</li>";
}

.navlinks > li:last-child:after
{ 
    content:"";
}
```

You should never style your HTML in php, this is the correct wayt to do it.